# sonar-java-plugin XML file scanning for files that don't have .xml extension

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am wondering if there is an easy way to scan XML files that have a different extension than .xml.  On my project we have xml files that have a .otp and .otm extension that I would like to include in the scan.

Without forking and modifying the XmlFileSensor source file, to change the .xml file extension, is there an easier way to do this?

I am using SonarQube 6.7.2, and have forked sonar-java-plugin project, planning to modify the 5.2.0.13398 version, if I have to.

Comment: What kind of issues would you expect to detect on those files ? SonarJava only check for specific things in xml files regarding maven or config files for tomcat or struts.